# How can I dynamically add custom validators in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a case where I need to add and remove custom validators for different instances of the same object.

For example...

```
class MyCustomValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 ...
end

class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyCustomValidator
end
```

**Context A:**

```
Foo.new.valid? #=> This should use the custom validator
```

**Context B:**

```
f = Foo.new
f.class.clear_validators!
f.valid? #=> This should no longer call the custom validator
```

**Context C:**

```
f = Foo.new
f.class.clear_validators!
f.valid? #=> This should no longer call the custom validator


# This is where I need to do something to bring the validator back so I can run


f.valid? #=> This should use the custom validator
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyCustomValidator, if: :use_custom_validators?

  def use_custom_validators?
    !@custom_validator_disabled
  end

  def without_custom_validators(&block)
    prev_disabled, @custom_validator_disabled = @custom_validator_disabled, true
    @custom_validator_disabled = true
    instance_eval(&block)
    @custom_validator_disabled = prev_disabled
  end

end

f = Foo.new
f.valid?      # Custom validator used
f.without_custom_validators do
  valid?      # Custom validator not used
end
f.valid?      # Custom validator used
```

Comment: Mm, that seems rather verbose. I know I'm able to do something like this: `self.class.send :validates_with, MyCustomValidator ` -- but was hoping there was a handy API that didn't require the meta calls.

Comment: You don't want to execute anything against the class, as it will affect all the objects of given class.

Comment: Right, but I can re-assign the default validators after the lifecycle of the object. I suppose there isn't a simple reversal of the `#clear_validators!` method.

Comment: You should not do this. If you'll ever host your application on multi-threaded server you will encounter many mysterious bugs.

Comment: So by that logic, all metaprogramming that dynamically defines methods, etc is out?

Comment: @Nathan - No, by this logic you need to meta-program with multi-threading in mind. Modifying classes in runtime is extremely risky, as it will affect all the existing objects of that class, in all threads. You can however modify object eigenclass (which has always a single instance). Metaprograming is pretty much the reason why I love ruby, but you need to be extra careful while doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not completely sold on your approach to the problem, but I'm selecting your answer because you pointed me in the right direction. In particular, you reminded me of the eigenclass, which I haphazardly neglected and to your point, could have found myself in a world of hurt. Thanks for that! FYI, I think the way I will end up solving it is modifying the singleton's eigenclass `#_validators` method. If that doesn't work, I'll re-read your approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the necessity to use a validator is defined by certain **state** of the object, you can use a [`state_machine` gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) and explicitly define a state flag. After that, you can define [state-specific validations](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#activemodel).

For that to work, you need to define two states with an extra validation only defined on one of them. Then you need to make an event that transitions from the "clean" to "validated" state (or whatever you call them).

Example:

```
class LockableSwitch < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine initial: :off
    state :off # It's probably redundant. I dunno.
               # if you're not storing state as strings, you'd specify
               # state :off, value: 0 # if `state` column was an integer
    state :on do
      # Can only be switched on if a key is inserted
      validates :key, presence: true
    end

    event :switch do # An event that causes the apple to become ripe
      transition :off => :on # `=>` justifies the use of that old syntax
      transition :on => :off # The first matched transition is used
    end
  end
end

@l = LockableSwitch.new # :off by default
@l.switch! # fails, bang-method throws an error on failed transition
@l.key = "something"
@l.switch! # works
```

It's *yet another library* and extra memory/complexity (even though not too much), but it makes your code much clearer in "what it does".

Comment: Hmm, problem is probably too robust for this solution. I've simplified it for posting the question, but in real terms my use case requires swapping in different combinations of custom validators given different contexts. It's for a validation framework in my current code base.

Comment: @Nathan You can define multiple state machines in one class, bound to separate state flags. The code, however, will be a bit uglier, but just a tiny bit.